# derived columns in sybase

Tags: sql, view, sybase

I am writing a query to define a view on a `Sybase Database`. Consider following example

```
SELECT a, (b+c+d-e) AS derived_1, (b+c+d-e)+2 AS derived_2, (b+c+d-e)+4 as derived_3
FROM TABLENAME
```

You can see I calculate a value using some logic(b+c+d-e), apply some more logic and return values for different derived columns. Is there any way so that I can just write (b+c+d-e) once ?

Something like

```
SELECT a, (b+c+d-e) AS derived_1, derived_1+2 AS derived_2, derived_1+4 as derived_3
FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the calculation in a subquery,

```
SELECT  a, 
        derived_1 + 2 AS derived_2, 
        derived_1 + 4 AS derived_3
FROM
        (
            SELECT  a, (b+c+d-e) AS derived_1 
            FROM    TABLENAME
        ) x
```